# Chart.js - Draw charts with opposite bars - How to set both the y-axis ends to positive number?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to draw a chart with opposite bars like this (please ignore the yellow part):
[image]

This is my attempt using Chart.js:

[image]

You can see that there are 2 things need to be fixed:

1. The blue and red bar should be stacked
2. Both ends of the y-axis should show positive numbers

How can I achieve those ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [stacking](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#stacked-bar-chart) and [custom ticks](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats) feature to produce the result you want.

[Sample JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d8d9r7fw/7/)

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('wrapper').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'bar',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "My First dataset",
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
            stack: 'a'
        }, {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(2, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(2, 99, 132)',
            data: [-10, -110, -15, -12, -120, -130, -145],
            stack: 'b'
        }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                stacked: true
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                stacked: true,
                ticks: {
                    callback: function (value, index, values) {
                        return value < 0 ? -value : value;
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```